# Solving the ODE $3 x y(x) \cos(x)+ 3 y(x) \sin(x) = \sqrt{9x^2 \sin(x)^2 + 1} y'(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please help me to solve the following differential equation:

$$3 x y(x) \cos(x)+ 3 y(x) \sin(x) = \sqrt{9x^2 \sin(x)^2 + 1} y'(x)$$

I tried using Variation of Parameters, Laplace transform and also undetermined coefficients, but nothing works.

Also I was not able to solve it with Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the differential equation but the evaluation of the integral.

$$3 x y(x) \cos(x)+ 3 y(x) \sin(x) = \sqrt{9x^2 \sin(x)^2 + 1} y'(x)$$
$$ \ln y =3\int \frac {x \cos(x)+  \sin(x) }{ \sqrt{9x^2 \sin(x)^2 + 1} }dx=3I$$
In case $\sin(x)^2=\sin^2 x$ Note that: 
$u=x\sin x \implies u'=\sin x + x \cos x$
$$\implies I=\int \frac {du }{ \sqrt{(3u)^2+ 1} }$$
Then you can try hyperbolic function substitution as suggested by Maximilian Janisch in the comment.
But if you mean $\sin(x^2)$ then it's another problem.

Comment: The integral simply is $$\operatorname{arcsinh}(3x\sin(x))$$

Comment: Yes @MaximilianJanisch but I have some doubt about the sin function at the denominator. it's no clear for me what OP means.